# Remove duplicate characters using Javascript

Tags: javascript, duplicates

I am trying to achieve the following output but keep coming up short. Not  sure I am taking the correct approach on this one. I looking to only allow only letters in the field also.

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="input-field" onkeyup="myFunction()">
```

Js:

```
const remDup= s=> s.split("").filter((e,i,f)=>f.indexOf(e)==i).sort().join("")
const myFunction = (e) => {
  let str = document.getElementById('input-field').value
  //Only allow letters no other characters
  if(("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ").indexOf(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode))===-1){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  console.log(remDup(str))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic will probably be better if you iterate over the string, `filtering` it by whether the lower-case version of the character being iterated over exists in a `Set` that you add to on every iteration.

Note that you *do* need to transform the character to lower-case before you test, which your current code isn't doing (nor does it look to be checking for duplicate characters):

```js
const myFunction = (e) => {
  const input = document.getElementById('input-field').value;
  const alphaInput = input.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '');
  const haveChars = new Set();
  const outputArr = [...alphaInput].filter((char) => {
    const lower = char.toLowerCase();
    if (haveChars.has(lower)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      haveChars.add(lower);
      return true;
    }
  });
  const strWithoutDupes = outputArr.join('');
  console.log(strWithoutDupes);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-field" onkeyup="myFunction()" value="AbraCadABraAlakAzam">
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a slightly shorter version that you can write using `Set`:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input-field');
input.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp, false);
const re = /[a-zA-Z]/;

function handleKeyUp(e) {

  // `reduce` over the value comparing the current element
  // to a lowercase list of previous iterated letters  
  const deduped = [...e.target.value].reduce((acc, el) => {
    const k = el.toLowerCase();
    if (!re.test(el) || acc.tmp.has(k)) return acc;
    acc.tmp.add(k);
    acc.out.push(el);
    return acc;
  }, { out: [], tmp: new Set() }).out.join('');
  console.log(deduped);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-field" value="AbraCadABraAlakAzam">
```

Comment: Letters are still being duplicated  - "AbraCdBlkzm"

Comment: It just verifies lowercase letters now. @user992731. I assume that's what you mean.

Comment: Upper and lower. Desired output is ""AbrCdlkzm". Big fan of this shorter version

Comment: So if there's an uppercase A there shouldn't be a lowercase a.

Comment: I only want to keep the first occurrence regardless of case.

Comment: Updated. Not quite as succinct as the previous answer, but it answers the question now :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that solves your problem in O(n) time and space.

```
const removeDups = (léString) => {
  const strArray = léString.split('')
  const charsSeen = {}
  let stripped = ''
  strArray.forEach(char => {
    if (!charsSeen[char.toLowerCase()]) {
      stripped += char
      charsSeen[char.toLowerCase()] = true
    }
  })

    return stripped
  }

  console.log(removeDups('AbraCadABraAlakAzam'))
```